# Function mutates an object argument after execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a function that takes an object argument and should generate a string value from this argument. I need to use this argument in another function but upon execution of the first function, the argument is changed.

This is the function that takes the object argument

```
export const  generateCron(cronRules: any): string {
   const cronKeys: Array<string> = ['minute', 'hour', 'day', 'month', 'year'];
   cronKeys.forEach(key => {
     if (!cronRules[key]) {
       cronRules[key] = '*';
     }
   });
   const { minute, hour, day, month, year } = cronRules;
   const cron: string = `${minute} ${hour} ${day} ${month} ${year}`;
   return cron;
 }
```

This is how am calling the function

```
    const { cron } = data;
    console.log(cron)
    const cronRules: string = generateCron(cron);
    console.log(cron)
```

suppose I have the cron object as `{ minute: 1, hour: 2 }` the 
function returns `1 2 * * *` as expected. but consoling the cron
object(second console) the object has already been changed to 
`{ minute: 1, hour: 2, day: '*', month: '*', year: '*' }`

could someone please help me understand what is happening

Comment: `cron` is `cronRules` inside the `generateCron` function and you do this `cronRules[key] = '*'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you iterate `cronRules` inside a loop, you need to take reference of `cronRules` and make a change on it.

```
const ref = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cronRules));

   const cronKeys: Array<string> = ['minute', 'hour', 'day', 'month', 'year'];
   cronKeys.forEach(key => {
     if (!ref[key]) {
       ref[key] = '*';
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in javascript, so when you call

```
cronRules[key] = '*';
```

you are changing the "cron" object that you passed into the function.

Instead of messing with the cron object, you could use this for the entire function:

```
const { minute, hour, day, month, year } = cronRules;
const cron: string = `${minute || '*'} ${hour || '*'} ${day || '*'} ${month || '*'} ${year || '*'}`;
return cron;
```

Which accomplishes the same task without modifying the original "cron" object.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
 cronRules[key] = '*';
```

You are mutating your object passed to the function, since javascript is a pass-by-reference language for object